# MailKit - moving letter to trash

Tags: c#, mailkit

how can I move letters to the trash? Now I just delete the letter from the server use next code:

```
client.DeleteMessage(0);
client.Disconnect(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the POP3 protocol, you cannot move messages into a server-side Trash folder.

You can only do that using IMAP.